# How do you add JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am making a GUI in Java, and I was wondering how do you add user inputs (integers) in a JTextField? If so, please post with some code so I can understand. (I am just a beginner programmer)

Comment: This isn't really a question. But here is the JavaDoc for JTF: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Comment: I can't understand the question. Are you asking how to add a text field to a frame? Or how to populate a text field with an integer value? Or something else?

Comment: Basically how to add a user input. If the user enters 5 in the JTextField, and 10 in another JTextField, I want to know how to add them together. But you cant add 2 JTextFields, so I was wondering if there is a statement to change the JTextField into an int.

Answer (score 2):

What all you need to do:

```
jTextField.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
```

Because `JTextField` takes a `String` to set its value you have to convert the `int` to `String`.

See [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A JTextField contains text. You get this text using `textField.getText()`, which returns a String. This String might happen to represent a valid integer. If you want to get the value of the integer, you need to transform the String into an int. That's done using the `Integer.parseInt()` method:

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
```

Of course, if one of the text fields contains text that doesn't represent an integer, you'll get an exception, as documented in the [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) javadoc.

Given your question, it seems you don't really understand basic notions such as types, and basic classes such as String and Integer. My advice would be to forget about Swing for the moment, and exercise with basic programs not involving any UI.